# FormBuilderDateTimePicker theme attribute not working

Tags: flutter, themes

there is a theme attribute in FormBuilderDateTimePicker.
but it keeps warn me

""The method 'DatePickerTheme' isn't defined for the type '_MyPageState'.""

```
             FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
              theme: DatePickerTheme(),//what is the problem??
              name: 'date',
              locale: Locale('ko'),
              onChanged: (val) async {
                await getReserveTime(val);
              },
              inputType: InputType.date,
              selectableDayPredicate: setDayPredicate,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "--날짜 선택--",
              ),
              firstDate: new DateTime.now(),
              lastDate: DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 60)),
              validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                FormBuilderValidators.required(
                  context,
                  errorText: '빈칸을 입력해주세요',
                ),
              ]),
            ),
```

Comment: Try to import the package containing your class `DatePickerTheme()`

Comment: thank you, the errors gone but still it won't apply to my app... i'm figuring it out